# How can I read Authorization header from a REST based WCF service?

Tags: wcf, restful-authentication

How can I read Authorization header information from a REST based WCF service?

Answer (score 14):

Actually since you ask for a REST based WCF service I think you should use

```
WebOperationContext.Current.IncomingRequest.Headers
```

in order to get the HTTP headers in the request.

Comment: I used this to read the Authorization header:


`var auth = WebOperationContext.Current.IncomingRequest.Headers["Authorization"];`

Answer (score 5):

You are trying to read the http header.

```
OperationContext.Current.OutgoingMessageProperties
or
OperationContext.Current.IncomingMessageProperties
```